# How to chain eventemitter next method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to execute some other code once event emitted and done. Is there a way to chain the .next() block like this?

```
@Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
this.myEvent.next({‘test string’}).onComplete(console.log('done');
```

Comment: What do you mean by the event is "done"? The event is emitted the very moment you called `next` on it. If you need to wait for some consumer of the event to do something with it, you need to make the consumer tell you about that. A shared service is one way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to monitor this out of the component that emits the event as this is supposed to be kind of "fire and forget".

What you could do is define another @Input-value which gets emitted by the parent component as soon as the "post-event actions" are done. If you monitor this you definitely know when to start follow-up actions.

Answer (score 2):

`EventEmitter` is an abstraction over RxJS `Subject` (this is a subject to change), and `Subject` implements both `Observable` and `Observer`. `next` isn't an operator, it can be seen in [`Observer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html) interface that `next` returns no value and cannot be chained.

As for the code above, `EventEmitter` has `emit` method for that, while `next` belongs to `Subject` API, so `emit` should be preferred:

```
@Output() myEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
this.myEvent.emit({‘test string’});
```

There is no `onComplete` method and there is no need for it. Outputs are supposed to stay incomplete until component destruction.

It could be done with

```
this.myEvent.subscribe(null, null, () => console.log('done'));
```

But this would result in additional subscription. All destroy logic should go to respective lifecycle hook:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  console.log('done');
}
```